# Inno Setup Compiler "Cannot find the path specified" error with long paths

Tags: inno-setup, filepath, node-modules, max-path

I am using a `.iss` script to build an **exe** file inside [Inno Setup Compiler](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). I need to package some **node_modules** into this application so I have a line under `[Files]` which looks like this:

```
Source: "{#SourcePath}Encore.Warehouse.UI\bin\Warehouse_Release\warehouse\*"; \
    DestDir: "{app}\warehouse"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

When I compile, I receive this error:

[image: The system cannot find the path specified.]

Here is the compiler output:

[image: Compiler Output]

So, it *appears* to be running fine up until it aborted. My initial thought was that the `browser.js` doesn't exist but after double checking, this is not the case. Also, I'm using a wildcard in the source path so **the compiler knows the file exists**, but it seems to be having trouble compressing it.

One other thing that *could* be causing the issue is the file path length. Node modules usually end up having **ridiculous file path lengths** due to nested dependencies. In this case, the path length is **260**. Assuming this is what's causing the problem, is there any way to get around it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's definitely due to a long path. Normally Windows applications cannot process paths longer than `MAX_PATH` (260 characters).
See [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation) in Microsoft documentation.

A common workaround is prefixing the path with `\\?\` (again see the Microsoft article above). The prefix can be used for absolute paths only. But Inno Setup compiler chokes on that with the `Source` attribute. It looks for `:` and it accepts only path that either have a drive letter only before the `:` or that use `compiler:` or `userdocs:` prefixes.

You can hack that by using an UNC path with a volume ID (hence no colon).

Use the `mountvol` command to find the UNC path for your source drive.

And then you will have the same problem with a long path with the `DestDir` attribute, while installing (not when compiling). There, there's no problem with the colon, so you can simply use the `\\?\` prefix.

```
Source: "\\?\Volume{bb919c3e-bdb1-42b8-9601-6715becd8683}\{#SourcePath}Encore.Warehouse.UI\bin\Warehouse_Release\warehouse\*"; \
    DestDir: "\\?\{app}\warehouse"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

---

Of course, if the problem is caused by a root path being too long already, you can fix the problem simply be moving the source files to a folder with a shorter path. Or you can use [`subst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst) to create a virtual drive or you can create a symlink/directory junction.

Answer (score 2):

Falling into the same issue, here below is more details on workaround with [subst](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst) as described in comments and accepted answer.

Here below is content of some `precompile.bat` file to associate some local path with the `A:` drive letter

```
@echo off
REM NB: Removing any previous association to be sure new one will work
subst A: /D 1> NUL 2>&1
subst A: "%~dp0.."
```

And content of some `postcompile.bat` to remove association in the end

```
@echo off
subst A: /D 1> NUL 2>&1
```

NB1: Careful, once associated, it is difficult to navigate upper paths directly within the `.iss` script because **`A:\..` is still `A:\` !** (I fall into the issue, so worth to know). Association should then be made with closest top-most folder of all required files directly in `precompile.bat`.

NB2: I don't know if feasible to remind for any previous association and restore it in the end

These steps can be added to the `.iss` script as follow:

```
[PreCompile]
Name: "precompile.bat"; Flags: cmdprompt redirectoutput

[PostCompile]
Name: "postcompile.bat"; Flags: cmdprompt redirectoutput
```

Note finally that `[PreCompile]` and `[PostCompile]` sections will execute from the IDE only. They won't execute from the command line (at least with inno 5.5.9), I also fall into this... so complete compilation from command line should look like:

```
call "precompile.bat"
call "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Inno Setup 5\ISCC.exe" "myscript.iss"
call "postcompile.bat"
```

NB: I think calling `Compil32.exe /cc "myscript.iss"` (IDE compiler) instead of `ISCC.exe` (command-line compiler) should run `[PreCompile]` and `[PostCompile]` sections but in my case I had to pass extra `/D` options to the compiler so it was not possible to call `Compil32.exe` directly.

Comment: Note that the `[PreCompile]`/`[PostCompile]` is a feature of some Inno Setup extensions. It does not work in Inno Setup itself (neither GUI nor the commandline).